# Считывание слов файла

Tags: c++

В-общем решил считать слова из файла. Делаю это так:

```
ifstream file("file.txt",ios::in);
char buff[512];
char word[128];
vector<string> v;
string temp;
while(file.good())
{
     file.getline(buff,512,' ');
     sscanf(buff,"%s",word);
     temp.assign(word, strlen(word));
     v.push_back(temp);
}
```

И все бы ничего, да вот беда, при переходе на новую строчку, первое слово новой строки всегда отбрасывается. Пробовал перегнать в файл без переводов строки, вышло еще хуже (sscanf стал считывать всю строку вместе с пробелами несмотря на Delimiter).
В-общем подскажите как быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И все бы ничего, да вот беда, при переходе на новую строчку, первое слово новой строки всегда отбрасывается.

Все правильно. Допустим у вас есть две строки, в них по два слова

> 123 456
>
> 789 000

На первой итерации будет прочитано `123` и положится в вектор. На второй итерации будет будет прочитано `456\n789`, (т.е. конец первой строки + первое слово из второй строки) т.к. Вы указали разделитель 'пробел'. `sscanf` преобразует эту строку до `"456"`, а `"789"` откинет, т.к. перед ней строит `\n`.

Comment: Ух блин и вправду. Спасибо Вам большое за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Если в каждой строке файла представлено только одно слово, то легче всего использовать `operator >>` в цикле `while(file.good())` для записи результата в строку `std::string`, а затем ее помещать в вектор.

Если же слова разделены пробелами, то и в этом случае стоит считывать именно так, открыв файл в текстовом режиме (по-умолчанию так и есть), т.к. в этом случае терминаторами окончания чтения являются пробельные символы: пробел, табуляция, перевод строки и пр.

Comment: Слова также могут быть разделены символами пунктуации. Это тоже надо учесть.

Comment: В таком случае, вам стоило сформулировать более точнее вопрос - что может быть разделителем? Если разделитель переменный - то запятая, то пробел, - и заранее не известно, какой именно, то алгоритм немного усложнится.

Comment: Может разделитель необходимо в другом формате указывать? нашла такие примерчики :
* istream& std::getline( istream& is, string& s, charT delimiter );*
*  return getline( is, s, is.widen( '\n' ) );*